# Hola no me cargan los estilos css de mi xampp no se porque si lo tengo bien linkeado y en la consola no me muestra error

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En esta imagen como pueden ver linkeo el archivo, yo supe que todo archivo que estaba en la carpeta includes y esa carpeta dentro de vista es como si los archivos de head.php y footer.php estuvieran en la carpeta vista directamente por eso es que no le pongo los cuatro puntos, pero,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] aunque ponga los cuatro o los dos o escriba "http://localhost/assets/...", no me cargan, y con el linkeo que ven en esta imagen hace un par de días me daban

Comment: NO, la url  no es `http://localhost/assets/` sino  `http://localhost/Maxtier_1/assets/`

Comment: Bueno y de la forma normal? Osea con los puntos, no porque pero algunas veces si me da el css y otras veces no, tengo que reiniciar mi computador para que me carguen los estilos

Comment: si es necesario que reinicies el pc es por que el navegador esta guardando en cache los estilos y no los toma cuando esta erroneo o cuando cambias algo, usa el modo desarrollador del navegador y desactiva la cache para que el navegador no guarde nada y sempre busque actualizar los archivos